# Java - TextView refers to another TextView in Expendable List View Child

Tags: java, android, textview

I have question. I am programming List Adapter in Java / Android. I override method which returns View (it's expendable list view from Clicked item). The problem is that:

Log.i shows me:

- 05-17 14:04:50.494: I/createTextView(21790): 0 06 Salame
- 05-17 14:04:50.504: I/createTextView(21790): 1 11 Pancetta

But TextViews looks both:

- 1 11 Pancetta
- 1 11 Pancetta

It looks like TextView refers to last TextView. How to fix that?

```
@Override
              public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                           View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                  Log.e("SecondLevelAdapter", "getGroupView");
                  TextView tv = new TextView(OrderFirstGridPage.this);

                   if((myArrayProductList.get(groupPosition).get(0).getFlgZlozony() == 1)) {

                       Log.i("createTextView", String.valueOf(counterProductName)+" "+myArrayProductList.get(groupPosition).get(counterProductName).toString());
                       tv.setText(myArrayProductList.get(groupPosition).get(counterProductName).toString());
                       counterProductName++;
                           }
                   tv.setPadding(22, 7, 7, 7);
                   tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT); 
                   tv.setTextAppearance(OrderFirstGridPage.this, R.style.TextLarge);
                   tv.setTextSize(25);

                     return tv;
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using LayoutInflater would be abetter way:

```
      @Override
  public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
    ViewGroup parent) {

   if (convertView == null) {

    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null);

  }

  TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
   if((myArrayProductList.get(groupPosition).get(0).getFlgZlozony() == 1)) {

                   Log.i("createTextView", String.valueOf(counterProductName)+" "+myArrayProductList.get(groupPosition).get(counterProductName).toString());
                   tv.setText(myArrayProductList.get(groupPosition).get(counterProductName).toString());
                   counterProductName++;
                       }
  tv.setPadding(22, 7, 7, 7);
               tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT); 
               tv.setTextAppearance(OrderFirstGridPage.this, R.style.TextLarge);
               tv.setTextSize(25);

 return convertView;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't show anything. TextView -> tv -> seems to be null when it refers to R.id.SomeTextView;; and is blank when I am trying to make my TextView.

Comment: which layout did you inflate? Have you inflate your group layout?